# What do I do if Mint doesnt have my native resolution as a display option?

Tags: linux-mint, display-settings

I have two displays. A monitor and an hdtv.

The monitor works because its 1920*1080 but my tv is 1366*768 and that isn't a resolution option.

I tried the next one up and it looks too pixelated for me.

Any way I can import this resolution into Mint?

My graphics card is a gtx 750ti if it matters.

Comment: Your GPU definitely supports 1366x768. What's the output of `xrandr` ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/877) helped me add a custom  resolution.

Comment: If you add a self-contained answer which describes what you did, this would be useful to others even if the link you quote goes away at some point.